# preg_replace(), removing string containing '+' char

Tags: php

I am having an issue removing "%3Cbr+%2F%3E" from my string using the preg_replace function. My assumption is that the '+' char is being interpreted incorrectly. Here my code:

```
$address = preg_replace('/%3Cbr+%2F%3E/', '', urlencode($address));
```

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `+` is a special character in regular expression. It is a quantifier and means that the preceding expression can be repeated one or more times.

Escape it with `\+` and it should work:

```
$address = preg_replace('/%3Cbr\\+%2F%3E/', '', urlencode($address));
```

But since you’re replacing a static expression, you could also use `str_replace`:

```
$address = str_replace('%3Cbr+%2F%3E', '', urlencode($address));
```